# Underscore not allow for Control's property name

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "R-F"; // ArgumentException...not a valid value
```

[image]

```
btn.Name = "RF"; // OK
```

Why can't I name a control with string that contains underscore or hyphen, while I can name a class or an object variable with one?

Comment: You can't name a class with a hyphen.

Comment: You should clean up your question, although you mention hyphen in a sentence the entire question reads underscore yet you're using a hyphen or a minus sign.

Comment: This question is just wrong all around. You **can** name the button with an **underscore** but you're using a **hyphen** which is not allowed. Please clarify exactly what you are asking for help with here.

Comment: And you can not name a class or a variable something with a hyphen or minus sign, that's not legal either. But you can, same as with that button, name it something with an underscore, including in both cases *just* an underscore. This is legal: `btn.Name = "_";` as is this: `var _ = 10;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the name will be used as an identifier in XML.

In any case, the limitiation is clearly spelled out in the documentation for [FrameworkElement.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx) which reads:

> The string values used for Name have some restrictions, as imposed by the underlying x:Name Directive defined by the XAML specification. Most notably, a Name must start with a letter or the underscore character (_), and must contain only letters, digits, or underscores. For more information, see [WPF XAML Namescopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx).

So as per the documentation, underscores **are** legal. **Hyphens**, however, are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a hyphen in a class/object's name. Underscores are fine.